# How to convert a linkedlist to an array in c#?

Tags: c#, arrays, linked-list

For a school project I am making an RPN calculator. This calculator has an abstract class Stack where three different implementations of stacks derive from. One of them is a linked list stack. For these stacks I have to show what values are on the stack. To do this I use an array. For my arraystack and list stack it was easy, but I can't figure out how to convert a linked list to an array. What is the best way to do that?

This is the code that I use for my linked list.

```
public class Node
{
    public int data;
    public Node next;

    public Node(int i)
    {
        data = i;
        next = null;
    }

    public void Add(int i)
    {
        if (next == null)
        {
            next = new Node(i);
        }
        else
        {
            next.Add(i);
        }
    }        
}
public class MyLinkedList
{
    private Node headNode;

    private int count;

    public MyLinkedList()
    {
        headNode = null;
        count = 0;
    }

    public int Count()
    {
        return count;
    }

    public void Add(int i)
    {
        if (headNode == null)
        {
            headNode = new Node(i);
        }
        else
        {
            headNode.Add(i);
        }
        count++;
    }
```

Comment: You presumably know how to visit each node of your linked list. Therefore: (1) Count all the nodes by visiting each one (or use an existing `count` if one exists), (2) Create an array of that size, (3) Visit each node again, this time copying each node into successive elements of the array.

Answer (score 1):

1. Implement `IEnumerable` on your LinkedList
2. `using System.Linq;`
3. Call `ToArray` on the LinkedList.

Implementing `IEnumerable` is trivial. Simply start at the root node in your list, `yield return Node.data;`, and move to the next node.  Rinse and repeat until the next node is `null`.

Answer (score 1):

As @Will suggested, I would implement `IEnumerable<int>` by your class. That will bring you to powerful world of LINQ where you will be able to convert your linked list to array, list, or just filter nodes:

```
public class MyLinkedList : IEnumerable<int>
{
    // your code here

    public IEnumerator<int> GetEnumerator()
    {
        Node current = headNode;

        while(current != null)
        {
            yield return current.data;
            current = current.next;
        }
    }

    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Now you can use all LINQ extensions with your class:

```
MyLinkedList myList = new MyLinkedList();
myList.Add(10);
myList.Add(15);
myList.Add(20);

int[] array = myList.ToArray();
List<int> list = myList.ToList();
// items above 13
var items = myList.Where(i => i > 13);
```

Comment: Never worked with Linq consciously nor with IEnumberable. Why do use `<int>`?

Answer (score 0):

Add a new method to your class.

```
public class MyLinkedList
{
  ... keep existing methods here ...

  public int[] ToArray() {
    var result = new int[count]();
    var index = 0;
    var node = headnode;
    while (node != null) {
      result[index] = node.data;
      node = node.next;
    }

    return result;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Eh... Something like that?

```
public class MyLinkedList {
  ...
  public Node[] ToArray() {
    // You´ve got pre-computed count - let´s use it
    Node[] result = new Node[count]; 

    Node node = headNode;

    for (int i = 0; i < result.Length; ++i) {  
      result[i] = node;
      node = node.next;
    }

    return result;
  }
}
```

P.S. *public fields* like `next` in the `Node` class is a *bad practice*. Convert them into *properties*